# Guardar en un nuevo archivo todo lo que imprimo en mi archivo Python

Tags: python

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo que busca un numero en dicha columna y luego imprime algunas lineas que esta por encima y por debajo:

```
                import collections
                import sys
                import itertools
                with open(archivo.txt) as f:
                    before = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
                    for line in f:
                        if "UN_NRO" in line[50:60]:
                            sys.stdout.writelines(before)
                            sys.stdout.write(line)
                            sys.stdout.writelines(itertools.islice(f, 10))
                            break
                        before.append(line)
```

Necesito guardar todas esas lineas en otro archivo "resumen.txt" agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes abrir dos archivos, uno para leer y otro para escribir, en el mismo contexto (línea `with`) y luego usar ambos dentro. Para escribir usa `fichero.write()` o `fichero.writelines()`.

Es decir, en tu caso:

votar en contra
favorito
Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo que busca un numero en dicha columna y luego imprime algunas lineas que esta por encima y por debajo:

```
import collections
import sys
import itertools
with open("archivo.txt") as entrada, open("resultado.txt", "w") as salida:
    before = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
    for line in entrada:
        if "UN_NRO" in line[50:60]:
            salida.writelines(before)
            salida.write(line)
            salida.writelines(itertools.islice(f, 10))
            break
        before.append(line)
```

He corregido un *bug* que tenías, pues `archivo.txt` lo habías puesto sin comillas. No he entrado tampoco a valorar qué haces dentro del bucle, ya que no has explicado qué se espera como resultado, pero me parece muy raro y rebuscado (seguro que puede hacerse sin `collections` ni `itertools`).